# Vuejs access scss files content

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, document.write

I'm printing a div I need the styles to add it to `document.write`

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
   @import "src/scss/myfile.scss";
</style>
```

I know that code will be compiled to raw css but I can't figure out how to get the content of it after it's been compiled